# Gradle: How to compile Android library with generic file name

Tags: android, gradle

In my Gradle project, I have a module that depends on an Android library, in build.gradle I did this

```
compile (name: 'android-library', ext:'aar')
```

Now this Android library name will be renamed with a version number, the version number changes every now and then, like this

```
android-library-18.aar
```

To still be able to use this aar, I tried this

```
compile (name: 'android-library*', ext:'aar')
```

I got this error

```
Could not find: android-library*
```

It seems like I can't use wild card in the file name like this, so how can I include this aar in my build.gradle in a generic way?